# Is the metafont language a context free grammar?

Tags: metafont

Is the metafont language a context free grammar?

I am new to lexer/parser/compiler writing, and am trying to get a general idea how hard it would be to write a metafont compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.  The Metafont language is basicly a macro expander operating over a stream of tokens.  It's a ingenious but very complex design, that allows the syntax to be changeable at runtime.  Tokens are not *fixed*, like they are in most languages, but they are *variable*, their meaning can be changed at runtime.

Metafont makes a distinction between tokens used as part of variable names (named *tags*) and as syntactic elements (named *sparks*).  When the parser encounters a tag, it first looks up the meaning of the tag before doing any evaluation.  This has the consequence that the meaning of a stream of tokens may change completely during the execution of a metafont program!

Take the following example in mf:

```
$ mf
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
**expr
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metafont/base/expr.mf
gimme an expr: 1plus5
>> plus5
gimme an expr: begingroup let plus=+ endgroup
>> vacuous
gimme an expr: 1plus5
>> 6
```

The token stream `1plus2` parses as `1*plus2`, where
`plus2` is a variable, since `plus` is defined as a tag.
In the second expression we redefined `plus` as a *spark* with
the same meaning as `+`. (`begingroup` is needed to enclose
a command in an expression).  When we parse `1plus5` again, it
stands for `1 + 5`, so evaluates to `6`!

Macro expansion in metafont is very complex, it can expand variables,
but sparks can also contain macros, with different rules for expansion.
There are also expanders for infix functions of different fixity.
The best way to learn about this is to read the *metafontbook*.